# Compiler error:The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to upload an image in my project which is in c#.and my code in the submit button is following

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(
          Server.MapPath("Photos\\" + 
              System.Core.WebSecurity.GetUserName(Request) + ".jpg"));

Response.Write(
    "<html> <script> alert ( 'you have successfully uploaded' ); </script></html>");

Response.Redirect("studentcreated.aspx");
```

but on compiling it shows an error as

> The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   .

Then i try to solve this by adding system.core to reference. But still it shows the same error. I am using vs2008 asp3.5.

Comment: The only reference I can find to a `WebSecurity` class is in the  `WebMatrix.WebData` namespace. I've never heard of a `System.Core` namespace.

Comment: @user793987, are you sure you are using  `System.Core.WebSecurity.GetUserName(Request)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get username: `User.Identity.Name`

EDIT:
Add this reference: `using System.Web.Security;`